# Drawing frequently updated image in Java

Tags: java, image, user-interface, drawing

I have experience in Java, but not in GUI's. Here is the problem.

I have an image (or `byte[][]`), generated by my system, and I need to frequently redraw it. The image size is about 1500x500, and the update frequency is about once per 100-500 milliseconds.

Please note, that each time only a small part of the image is being updated: just several pixels on the right side. I need to shift the rest of the image to the left, so it should look like a moving image. I don't need to keep the left side which is out of image boundaries.

I looked on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218840/draw-an-image-of-growing-size-in-java), which is very helpful and works very fast, but I couldn't make if work on my image.

Questions:

- What is the most efficient (processing speed) way to implement this task.
- Please recommend me a suitable tutorial

Thanks!

Comment: A technique that works is to keep a "rolling index" into the image. You update the pixels in the row at index, and do two draws: from index+1 to maxIndex, and then from 0 to index, wrapping around back to the "new" pixels. You still have to handle locking (can't update image while swing is redrawing, etc). But that's not a trivial implementation, maybe someone will come up with a library or better technique...